# How to delete multiple elements by index at same time in array where indexes are not continuous?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array in javascript like

```
var A = [5,3,5,7,2,9,0,1,4,6,5,2];
```

how can I delete index 0,3,7,8 from the array in one step? Is this possible, or do I need to loop through each index I want to delete. Note the given indices I want to delete have no pattern and are random. They are also not sorted (the indices I want to delete).

Comment: What's wrong with a loop?

Comment: I want to know if possible in one step.

Comment: What constitutes a *step*?

Comment: One line without using a loop. Something like `A.delete(0,3,7,8);`.

Comment: It's impossible to to delete multiple non-continues elements from an array with a single operation. You have to iterate on some level.

Comment: Any such implementation that I can think of for such a `delete()` method would involve a loop

Comment: I agree you could use higher order functions from libraries like ramdajs to achieve this. But internally they will be using loop

Answer (score -1):

Introduce a method in the array's prototype. Now every array has this behavior automatically!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>

var del = function(indicesToDelete) {
for (i in indicesToDelete) {
console.info(this);
delete this[indicesToDelete[i]];
}
}

Array.prototype.del = del;

var arr = [10,20, 30, 40, 50, 60];

//del([1, 3]);

arr.del([1, 3]);
alert(arr);

var arr2 = [10000, 200000, 300000, 400000];

arr2.del([2, 4]);

alert(arr2);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoever voted this down doesn't understand the dynamic benefits of JavaScript.

Comment: Downvoter here. Whoever downvoted does understand that this modifies Array's prototype which is a dubious practice, and understands that your code still includes a loop and doesn't explain that it's not possible to iterate *somewhere* to accomplish what the OP is asking.

Comment: ... and your code deletes array indices by their property with `delete`, which is also dubious, and I doubt it was what the OP is asking about regarding deleting elements.

Comment: Explain dubious! And yes it does include a loop but it is now a feature of an array applicable to all arrays. This is the power of JS.

Comment: Deleting array indices breaks reasonable assumptions about arrays, tests for existence of an array element that was deleted will fail, and the length of the array isn't updated. While it is true you can modify built-in prototypes, in projects of a larger scope other than just you, it's a bad idea. Regarding the iteration to accomplish, the OP asks *"...Is this possible, or do I need to loop through each index I want to delete..."*, which your answer doesn't really touch on at all.

Comment: You cannot delete multiple elements from an array with a single step because each deletion involves shifting of array elements so if you somehow can instantly delete, to use your example, indexes `0,3,7,8`, in an array, after deleting at index `0`, array would shrink in size by 1 so all of your indices would be off by 1 and this off-by-1 margin would increment on each deletion.

Comment: @nem in this case this code would actually delete the property that is `arr[1]`, `arr[3]`, etc, and would not resize the or cause one-off errors. It breaks reasonably safe assumptions about arrays.

Comment: @jdphenix yeah, well i accidentally commented here instead on the actuall question so, oops :)